# Javascript after AJAX load?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using [Infinite Scroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) on my website: http://8wayrun.com/articles/soulcalibur-ii.22/category

As you scroll to the bottom, it will load the next page. As you scroll down though, you will see that one of the elements loaded in through the javascript contains a Twitter quote. Normally, Twitter quotes are automatically converted using Twitter's JS API into a Twitter element. However, because the page is being loaded through AJAX, its not activating the Twitter JS.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the below JS after loading new content:-

```
twttr.widgets.load();
```

The above statement will scan the complete document for any embedded tweets. In case you have the element within which the content has been added then pass that element as argument in the load function.

Comment: Is there a general statement I can do to make ALL javascript load? Twitter isn't the only issue, was just using it as an obvious example.

Comment: The above statement is only specific to Twitter as it enhances Tweets to look nice. You can create some utility functions which you can call to do some stuff again after new content came. However I don' think there is a way by which you can reload the all the JS present in browser and it won't be a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution would be something like:

```
let newScripts = main.getElementsByTagName('script');
// DANGER we eval these
[...newScripts].forEach( script=> {
  if(script.innerHTML) {
    eval( script.innerHTML );
  } else if(script.src) {
    let scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.src = script.src;
    document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
  }
});
```